# Loop through each line and delete it after

Tags: loops, batch-file, line, dos

I have a MS-DOS batch script that executes a custom command for each line in a specific text file. And I want it to delete each line after processed so that the next time I open the batch I can resume it from where I stopped without starting all over and executing the loop through the same lines. The lines only have numbers.

file.txt:

```
    76561197967664150
    76561197960466635
    76561197969570587
    76561197978933289
    76561198011880885
    76561197977884769
    76561198010665215
    76561198012847269
    76561197988209745
    76561197991756815
    76561197999860750
    76561198012060656
    76561198020700372
    76561198005281666
```

ALSO, if it is easier, the code may also delete 250 lines all at once after processed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write out the last number you processed to a file instead of deleting from the main file? That would make it much simpler. Next time you process the file, you skip numbers until you find the one you wrote out to disk.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care to rewrite your file with each processed line:

```
:loop
REM read first line:
set /p first=<file.txt
REM write changed file.txt:
  find /v "%first%" file.txt>file.tmp
  del file.txt
  ren file.tmp file.txt
echo processing %first%...
echo press any key for next line or CTRL-C to break
pause >nul
goto :loop
```

NOTE: if you *really* mean MS-DOS (which I doubt), this won't work.